# How to limit BigQuery job by slots

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I’d like to limit a BigQuery job (query) submitted with the Python SDK to use a certain amount of slots. For example, I have a provision with 400 slots in BigQuery (flat-rate). And let's say I've got a heavy query which uses 300 slots during execution (according to the statistics). I would like to define a lower limit for the job, let's say 100 slots. I admit that the execution will be slower, but it's fine. I just need the job not to "eat" more than 100 slots during the execution.

I found that it's possible to set a limit by bytes with `maximumBytesBilled` (described [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job#jobconfigurationquery)). Is it possible to set slots in a similar manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Currently, it's not possible to manually set the amount of slots that will be used by a query job.*

BigQuery automatically calculates how many slots each query requires, depending on query size and complexity. According to the Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/slots):

> Depending on complexity and size, a query might not require all the
> slots it has the right to, or it may require more. BigQuery
> dynamically ensures that, given fair scheduling, all slots can be
> fully used at any point in time.

You can raise a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) if you want BigQuery engineering team to work on it.

I'm not aware of your use case, however a workaround if you want a query to use specific slots would be to create/use a different project and allocate 100 slots to it.